# Chrome Iframe display White Box

Tags: iframe, google-chrome

Aloha,

currently my pligg template have following Iframe code :

```
<iframe height="0px;" width="0px;" frameborder="0" name="story_status"></iframe>
```

Its working fine on firefox, however on chrome, it display as white box..

after inspecting,

```
<iframe height="0px;" width="0px;" frameborder="0" name="story_status">
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
</iframe>
```

body have margin: 8px;

EDIT : [ view this on chrome & firefox, u can notice white box on chrome ]

```
<html>
<head><style>html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background : #000; color: #fff;">
aaaaa<iframe height="0px;" width="0px;" frameborder="0" name="story_status"></iframe>bbbbb
aaaaaaaaa
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to remove margin 8px as it display as white box on chrome?

thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I just put the <iframe> into <div> as follows:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;">
  <iframe ...></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me but instead of 'visibility:hidden', I placed 'overflow:hidden' for <div></div>.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display: block` on your `iframe`, it will obey the height and width rule then.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS rule *in the `<iframe>`*:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, try adding the following CSS rule to the parent page (which contains the `<iframe>`):

```
iframe {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, paste that on a html file and view on chrome.

Comment: You need to add that CSS rule to the page in the `<iframe>`.

Comment: still same, not working..

the iframe is : <iframe height="0px;" width="0px;" frameborder="0" name="story_status"></iframe>

after inspected = chrome, inspect element.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm playing with "visibility: hidden" and javascript. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS

```
html {
    font-size:0;
}
```