# iFrame Showing As White Box [Tested In Chrome & Firefox]

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, iframe

```
<iframe src="https://github.com/EdenCrow" width="100%" height="100%">Failed Message</iframe>
```

The code above results in a white box and a grey frame in the browser instead of showing my GitHub page, as it is supposed to. As mentioned in the title I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox and both give the same effect.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Iframe display White Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085530/chrome-iframe-display-white-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the response headers for your page http://jsfiddle.net/YDNnN/ using Firebug or simliar you can see that GitHub is returning the x-frame-options response header as deny which stops the page being rendered in a frame.

Another post on here [Github gist page won't load in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649361/github-gist-page-wont-load-in-iframe) suggests using the Github API to get the data you need.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. If some-one could tell me exactly how it would be possible to get the effect I wish to achieve then please do say - in the mean time I will look into using the GitHub API.